# right click on html link which execute javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When i click a link, i want to execute a javascript function to get the dynamic url.
So i did like below.

```
<a href="javascript:myredirect()"> a link </a>
```

With this code, I cannot see the default context menus provided by browsers like 'open link in new tab' or 'open link in new window' when i right click the link.
I tried like below too.

```
<a href="#" onclick="myredirect()"> a link </a>
```

In this case, i can see the link context menu, but it does not execute the "myredirect()" when i do the 'open link in new tab' menu.

Is there a way to run a javascript code when i open link in new tab or new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, you can't.

But since you are using JS anyways, you can just use it to change the `href` attribute in `<a`, so by the time the user clilcks on the link, it's already pointing to the right URL.

Comment: thnx. I want to make a dynamic url based on user input.

Comment: Right, i'll follow that way. thnx.

Comment: Alternative - make the link a span with a pointer cursor which will  not give the possibility of opening the link in a new browser